# How to get the data from one dictionary and place in another dictionary using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two dictionaries of data which needs to be compared and fetch the respective data from one dictionary to another:

netname = []

netstatus = []

Dict1:

```
data1: {
"node1":["id1",["net1","net2"]],
"node2":["id2",["net3","net4"]],
"node3":["id3",["net5","net1"]],
"node4":["id4",["net2","net5"]],
....
....
....
}
```

Dict2:

```
data2: {
"detail1":["net1","id1","netone","available"],
"detail2":["net2","id2","nettwo","available"],
"detail3":["net1","id3","netthree","not available"],
"detail4":["net4","id4","netfour","not available"],
"detail5":["net5","id4","netfive","available"],
"detail6":["net2","id2","netsix","available"],
....
....
}
```

I am trying to  get the complete details of each of every node in a tabular format using prettytable:

The code I am trying here is:

```
for node,values in data1.items():
    id = values[0]
    networks = values[1]
    for network in networks:
        if any(any(network in x for x in netlist) for netlist in data2.values()):
            if any((network in y for y in data2.values() if y[0] == network and y[1] == id)):
                for val in data2.values():
                    if (val[0] == network and val[1] == id):
                        nwinfo = netname.append(val[2])
                        nwstatus = netstatus.append(val[3])
          
            else:
                print("node id",id,"is not registered in network",network)
                                      
        else:
            print("Node is not registered in any networks..")
```

when I executed this code, I am getting false values. Do the **any(condition)** correct here or do I need to add anything to display the correct values after comparing data1 with data2.

- First any() condition in the above script is to check if *id* of data1 dict is present in entire dict data2
- second any() condition in the above script is to check if the *id* is connected to respective network or not

In the above case, I want to check if the **id** and the **net(n)** should be compared properly in dict1 and dict2 and display the respective values.

Comment: Is this a large dataset or a comparatively small one? I want to know if I should reshape the inputs for efficiency or just brute force in my answer.

Comment: 10 rows of data per dictionary set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way forward would be to reshape your inputs to make the join easier. I would do that with comprehensions based around a new "key" that would be the combination of "id" and "net".

You can uncomment the print statements to get a better look at what the reshaping is doing if you like.

```
data1 = {
   "node1":["id1",["net1","net2"]],
   "node2":["id2",["net3","net4"]],
   "node3":["id3",["net5","net1"]],
   "node4":["id4",["net2","net5"]],
}

data2 = {
   "detail1":["net1","id1","netone","available"],
   "detail2":["net2","id2","nettwo","available"],
   "detail3":["net1","id3","netthree","not available"],
   "detail4":["net4","id4","netfour","not available"],
   "detail5":["net5","id4","netfive","available"],
   "detail6":["net2","id2","netsix","available"],
}

data1_reshaped = [
   f"{cell}:{row[0]}"
   for row in data1.values() for cell in row[1]
]
#print(data1_reshaped)

data2_reshaped = {
   f"{x[0]}:{x[1]}": {"name": x[2], "status": x[3]}
   for x in data2.values()
}
#print(data2_reshaped)

netname = []
netstatus = []

## now it is a simple lookup based on an array of keys
for key in data1_reshaped:
   match = data2_reshaped.get(key)
   if not match:
      continue

   netname.append(match["name"])
   netstatus.append(match["status"])

print(netname)
print(netstatus)
```

This should give you:

```
['netone', 'netthree', 'netfive']
['available', 'not available', 'available']
```

If in the end you want something more like:

```
{
    'netone': 'available',
    'netthree': 'not available',
    'netfive': 'available'
}
```

The join step even simpler.